# How do I switch to another organization in the AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

My company has two organizations: one is the primary organization that my user is part of. The other is a new one created for testing purposes.

I need to switch to that organization to create an S3 bucket (and possibly some other resources) so that they will be owned by the other organization and not the one my user is part of. I supposedly have access to do so.

How do I do that?

I would be nice to know how to do it via browser and CLI both.

Thanks!

Comment: There’s not enough information to know exactly what information to provide. When you have an AWS “organization” one or more AWS accounts can be invited to it or created from the management account. However, the account logins all function independently. ie you login to the account you’re referring to by using the root username and password or IAM credentials created in that account. Same as logging in to any other account, including the one you’re currently using.  Creds are not shared. Unless you have slapped something like AWS SSO on top of it, in which case there are other ways to login.

Comment: Long story short you login with the credentials established in each member account.

Comment: Supposedly, I have permission to create S3 buckets for the other organization, but I can't login as that organization. IDK

Comment: we need to use proper terminology. An AWS “organization” is a collection of AWS accounts. There is no such thing as a “sub organization” as part of an AWS organization. It’s still not very clear what you’re asking for. Please do some research and update your question accordingly. Nonetheless, accessing ANY AWS account requires that you have some sort of credential in that account. If you don’t know what they are, then you’ll have to ask someone with access to that account. How you login to that account has no direct relationship with how you login to account you are using now.

Comment: Okay, I rephrased my question

Answer (score 0):

You must have two accounts in your AWS platform. One that you use currently has services running that I would call "Live" and the other one is a "Testing or Development" account in which you test before going live to make sure everything is running normally. (Live/Test-Dev)
Now if you created a testing account in the Live account and want to move it over to the Test account follow these instructions below.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/organizations-move-accounts/

As for the S3 bucket problem, double check your permission on credentials with other organziation. You might not have the correct permission for the S3 to do what you want to do.